# How to create e-commerce website

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, css

I really don't know how to make this question clear.

I realize e-commerce and blog websites are quit different from basic websites.

I am creating an e-commerce site from scratch, using HTML and CSS, javascript with a text editor (sublime text), which makes it tedious and time consuming.

I have different product pages (male cloths, female, baby, phones, jewelries, etc) of which are sub categorized under brands, types, styles, names, etc.

I also created a product detail / description, but I realize for each one  all these thousands of products, I will have to create a description for all.

Is there any way to accomplish this without having to recreate a description page for each of these thousand products?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Too broad for SO.  Just build something, fail, get back up off the floor, and get better each time.

Comment: I suggest picking one aspect of this project first and try to build that. You definitely do not need to create thousands of "description pages". A single "description page" template can be used and the different details can be dynamically inserted to create a specific "description page" for each item.

Comment: Question answered. Thanks.

Comment: absurd trying to build an ecommerce site from scratch with no background.... use an open source one to start

Comment: @Rico, it's good that you got your answer, but bear in mind that several questions like these (heavily downvoted) will lock your account automatically until the rep score improves. The culture here is much in favour of self-directed research, a serious attempt, and then asking about _specific_ problems if they crop up. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a  content management system (CMS), such as Drupal or Joomla.

There are CMS that are specific to e-commerce as well, such as Magento or OpenCart.

Comment: Thanks. I will have to start learning Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

you can use open source CMS like:
http://www.oscommerce.com/
http://virtuemart.net/
not very hard just install it into server and use it! :)

Comment: Okay. Thank you. I will check this one out too.